# Why does anchoredDraggable cause recomposition onDrag?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, draggable, jetpack

The official docs state that [changing the offset](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/bestpractices#defer-reads) of a composable should not cause a recomposition as long as you are using the lambda version of the composable.
Given the following composable, I'm unable to figure out why dragging the box is causing re-composition.

```
enum class DragValue { Start, End }

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun AnchoredDraggableBox() {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val state = remember {
        AnchoredDraggableState(
            initialValue = DragValue.Start,
            positionalThreshold = { totalDistance: Float -> totalDistance * 0.5f },
            velocityThreshold = { with(density) { 100.dp.toPx() } },
            animationSpec = tween(),
        ).apply {
            updateAnchors(
                newAnchors = DraggableAnchors {
                    with(density) {
                        DragValue.Start at 0.dp.toPx()
                        DragValue.End at 100.dp.toPx()
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(48.dp)
            .background(color = Color.Red)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(48.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .anchoredDraggable(
                    state = state,
                    orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
                )
                .offset {
                    IntOffset(
                        x = state
                            .requireOffset()
                            .toInt(),
                        y = 0
                    )
                }
                .background(color = Color.Blue)
        ) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Recomposing")
        }
    }
}
```

Starting from this initial state and dragging the box is causing 2 recompositions when the only thing changing is the offset.

[image: start]    ->
[image: end]

Is there anything I can do to prevent this recomposition or is it simply how compose works with [anchoredDraggable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/touch-input/pointer-input/migrate-swipeable)?